# Get ScriptOrigin from v8::Module

Tags: c++, v8, es6-modules

> It seems trivial, but I've searched far and wide.

I'm using [this resource to make v8 run with ES Modules](https://gist.github.com/surusek/4c05e4dcac6b82d18a1a28e6742fc23e) and I'm trying to implement my own search/load algorithm. Thus far, I've managed to make a simple system which loads a file from a known location, however I'd like to implement external modules. This means that the *known location* is actually unknown throughout the application. Take the following directory tree as an example:

```
~/
  - index.js
      import 'module1_index'; // This is successfully resolved to /libs/module1/module1_index.js

/libs/module1/
  - module1_index.js
      export * from './lib.js' // This import fails because it is looking for ./lib.js in ~/source
  - lib.js
      export /* literally anything */
```

The above example begins by executing the `index.js` file from `~`. When `module1_index.js` is executed, `lib.js` is looked for from `~` and consequently fails.  In order to address this, the files must be looked for relative to the file being executed at the moment, however I have not found a means to do this.

### First Attempt

I'm given the opportunity to look for the file in the `callResolve` method (main.cpp:280):

```
v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Module> callResolve(v8::Local<v8::Context> context, v8::Local<v8::String> specifier, v8::Local<v8::Module> referrer)
```

or in `loadModule` (main.cpp:197)

```
v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Module> loadModule(char code[], char name[], v8::Local<v8::Context> cx)
```

however, as mentioned, I have found no function by which to extract the `ScriptOrigin` from the module. I should mention, when files are successfully resolved, the `ScriptOrigin` is initiated with the **exact** path to the file, and is reliable.

### Second Attempt

I set up a stack, which keeps track of the current file being executed. Every import which is made is pushed onto the stack. Once the file has finished executing, it is popped. This also did not work, as there was no way to reliably determine once the file had finished executing.

It seems that the `loadModule` function does just that: *loads*. It does not execute, so I cannot pop after the module has loaded, as the imports are not fully resolved. The `checkModule`/`execModule` functions are only invoked on dynamic imports, making them useless to determining the completion of a static import.

I'm at a loss. I'm not familiar with v8 enough to know where to look, although I have dug through some [NodeJS source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/module_wrap.cc) looking for an implementation, to no avail.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
Jake.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about module resolution, but looking at V8's sources, I can see an [example](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/d8/d8.cc;l=947?q=ResolveModuleCallback) mapping a `v8::Module` to a `std::string absolute_path`, which sounds like what you're looking for. I'm not copying the whole code here, because the way it uses custom metadata is a bit involved; the short story is that it keeps a `std::unordered_map` to keep data about each module's source on the side. (I wonder if it would be possible to use `Module::ScriptId()` as that map's key, for simplification.)

[Code search](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/include/v8-script.h;l=231;drc=7a0b88f6d5c015fd3c280b58c7a99d8e1dca28ac;bpv=1;bpt=1) finds a bunch more example uses of `InstantiateModule`, mostly in tests. Tests often serve as useful examples/documentation :-)

Comment: Do you happen to know what the script ID is actually referring to? Is it generated, each time it is passed through to compile, or is it derived from the code / origin somehow?

Comment: It's just an internal ID, generated as `next_id = last_id + 1`. Definitely not derived from code or origin.

Comment: Understood. What about the `ScriptHash`?

Comment: I don't see a `ScriptHash` on `v8::Module`. If you mean `v8::Module::GetIdentityHash`, that's a (non-zero) random number.

Comment: Understood. I'll let you know how th implementation goes. I'm still not entirely convinced I understand your advice, but I'll give it my best shot. Thanks for your help